# Angular2 Router: What should be the routerLink to switch 2 outlets?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 outlets:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

and routes:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'user', component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'user', component: UsersComponent, outlet: 'popup'}
];
```

what should be the routerLink to output UsersComponent for both main and popup outlets?

Comment: Something like `['user', { outlets: { popup: 'user' }}]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

`<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: 'user', popup: 'user'}}]">Open Chat1</a>`